# Жесты в iOS

Tags: gestures, mobile-development, xcode, swipe, ios

Подскажите,  мне надо вызывать определенный метод, когда происходит жест свайпа вправо, НО! когда он происходит от левой границы экрана.

Цель чтобы у меня свайпом вправо внитри экрана открывалось одно меню, а свайпом от границы экрана открывалось другое меню.

Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

скажем ты настроил жест и задал ему `@selectot(swipeRightStateChanged:)`

тогда в методе:

```
- (IBAction)swipeRightStateChanged:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
     switch (sender.state) {
          case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:
          case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
                  CGPoint touch = [sender locationInView:self.view];
                  /* дальше можешь проверить где начинается свайп, на краю или нет, например: */
                  if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 70.0, self.view.bounds.size.height), touch) {
                      // swipe начинается на левой границе
                  } else {
                      // внутри view
                  }
                 break;
          }
          case UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized: {
                // ну а тут мы уже точно знаем что жест произошел
                break;
          }
     }   
}
```

еще один способ использовать 2 жеста:

либо 2 UISwipeGestureRecognizer, стать их делегатом и в методе делегата

```
- (BOOL)gestireRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGectureRecognizer *)gesture
{
      if (gesture == self.edgeSwipeGesture) {
          return (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 70.0, self.view.bounds.size.height), [gesture  locationInView:self.view]);
      } else if (gesture == self.swipeGesture) {
          return (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(70.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width - 70.0, self.view.bounds.size.height), [gesture  locationInView:self.view]);
      }
      return YES;
}
```

и еще один способ - это использовать для границы экрана **UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer** вместо UISwipeGestureRecognizer, не и обычный свайп для остального, тогда нужно будет реализовать метод делегата

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
     return NO;
}
```

хотя по умолчанию он должен итак работать нужным образом, но можно попробовать с ним поиграться, чтобы достичь нужного поведения, проверяя что за жест начался и какой хочет начаться.